# ngTable with server side loading doen't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ngTable to display a large table with data coming from the server. The initial data is displayed correctly. When I try sorting by a column or try going to the next page there is a request and correct response being sent and received, the getData function resolves it but the table isn't being updated in any way. It just shows the first page with the initial data.

HTML:

```
<table  class="table table-bordered" ng-table-dynamic="table.detailsParams with table.cols" >
                <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by $index">
                    <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{::row[col.field]}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

JS:

```
scope.$on('campaign-changed', function (event, args) {
                scope.campaign = args.campaign;
                scope.campaign.createdAt = moment(scope.campaign.createdAt).format('DD MMM, YYYY')

                scope.table.detailsParams = new NgTableParams({
                    count: 10,
                    sorting: { campaignName: "desc" }
                }, {
                    getData: function (params) {
                        // ajax request to api
                        if (typeof params.total() == 'undefined' || params.total() == 0) {
                            ajaxSrv.getDetailsTotalCount(scope.campaign.id, function (data) {
                                params.total(data.data[0]);
                            })
                        }
                        var req = ajaxSrv.getCampaignData(params.url(), scope.campaign.id).then(function (response) {
                            return $q.resolve(response.data.data);
                        })
                        return $q.resolve(req);
                    }
                });
            })
```

Comment: Where are you updating $scope.data in your on event ...?

Comment: Nowhere. There is no $scope.data in my code and there's no $scope.data in the examples for ngTable. There's only $scope.$data which is supposed to be updated with the getData function.